# Python beginner: function to fill dataframe with sentences does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, list-comprehension

I am trying to preprocess my data by creating new column with the preprocess function. For strange reasons when I try to execute the function the result is an empty column.

Comment: I tried to fix your title, but I really don't understand how it relates to the text in your question. Maybe I misunderstood what you tried to ask? Please review.

Comment: I review the question

Comment: @kely789456123 If the `lemmatize` function is returning exactly what you printed (in the comment) then it looks like it is a list with a single string in it that contains punctuation. It will be ignored by your `isalnum` test. Or is that comment not accurate?

Comment: @ongenz You are right for the printed (in the comment). Do you know how to remove punctuation Inside the string  and suppress the "single quote" ?

Comment: That is very strange. The `lemmatize` function is returning a list with a single string in it? It should return a list of lemmatised tokens, like this: `['compact', 'tout', 'intégrer', '.', 'euh', '...', 'communiquer', '.', 'je', 'penser', 'que', 'ce', 'être', 'déjà', 'pas', 'mal', '.']`. If you fix this then I think the rest of your code (at least the part that fills the DataFrame) will work. Where does this function come from?

Comment: I Added the lemmatize function. Ithink I take it on this website

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: @Vishal I find a solution thank you

Comment: @kely789456123 it would be good to leave your code and the solution you found as an example for others who might have the same problem.